# In-sample and out-sample backtest performance, how to do this?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, backtesting

I have a strategy in development that I am backtesting to optimize for parameters, a total of *N* combinations. Trying my best not to overfit.

I run the first backtest for the in-sample period and I get, say, *n* results that make money and *(N-n)* of the rest that don't. I rank the results by return or any other well-defined criteria, and get list *L1*.

Then I take the top performing *p*% of *n* parameters, run another backtest using those parameters on a different out-sample period. I get another similar ranked list, *L2*.

It's not surprising that *L1* and *L2* are slightly, and not dramatically, different (*L2* is shorter but similar order). What's your next step? Do I take the top *m*% of *L2* and use that for final third backtest on some more data and get *L3*? Then average the performance rankings of parameters of *L2* and *L3* use those as a final output? How would you pick what parameters to go with? I am constrained to run only 10 or so parameter sets at best, but I have hundreds that are doing well but are very, very close to each other in performance because some of them cluster around.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding your backtest is introducing a lot of sampling bias. You should use the traditional cross-validation of the training set and once you have calibrated your parameters on this you can try it out of sample. You should rather randomly pick a sample out of the training set, calibrate and validate, but choosing a top% introduces sample bias and is poorly stratified.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will try this